# Unsubscribe from a Feedburner email sent as text to my ATT mobile phone

Tags: feedburner

How do I unsubscibe from a Feedburner email that is sent as text to my ATT mobile phone? The unsubscibe link does not appear at the end of the email (text) message. I have tried replying with "stop", "block", etc with no success. There is no help or unsubscribe option on the originator's website.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried replying back with "unsubscribe" -- it's a long shot but commonly the old school way of doing things.